# Java.util.random - "Bound must be positive"

Tags: java, random, indexoutofboundsexception

I get this error:

```
java.lang.illegalException:
bound must be posotive
```

in the following line of code:

```
Random random = new Random();
Item randomItem;
randomItem = new Item("NAME_HERE", "DESCRIPTION_HERE", 0000);
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(randomItem.randomNames.size());   *** ERROR HERE?!
randomItem.name = randomItem.randomNames.get(randomNumber);
addItem(randomItem);
```

This only happens the SECOND time i call the above method. It looks like (if i try print out the size of the randomNames arraylist, that it actually gets to 0. But it should not... Here is the randomItem, where the randomNames arraylist is created.. Nothing else but the above code has influence. ????

```
public ArrayList<String> randomNames;
randomNames.add("Key");
randomNames.add("Rock");
randomNames.add("Balloon");
randomNames.add("Boot");
randomNames.add("Knife");
randomNames.add("Pencil");
```

Comment: Print `randomItem.randomNames.size()` before executing the line with the error

Comment: It looks like some code that we're not seeing here is causing randomNames.size() to be zero. Hard to say what's causing that based on what we're seeing here

Comment: Output is 6 as it should.

Comment: randomItem.randomNames.size() is probably returning 0

Comment: Yea, but why does it do that? There is not any other code than this, that refers to that arraylist.. :(

Comment: Try to find where it goes from 6 to 0 in the debugger.

Comment: I am pretty new to java, and using BlueJ. I am not sure how to use the debugger, unfortunately

Comment: Here's a [tutorial!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUUPTbWV0g8) And [another](http://www.bluej.org/tutorial/tutorial-201.pdf), and [another](http://undergraduate.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS1001/handouts/BlueJDebuggerTutorial.pdf)! So you call that method twice but you're only adding to your randomnames once? Or are they also in the same method?

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial links, i'll post the result of the debugger soon.. Yes, i add the six predefined names "key", "rock" etc ONCE. But i call the method to create a new randomItem with one of these random names TWICE. First time works, second time fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your randomItems array size is 0.  Check that

- randomNames is not declared static
- The Item constructor fills the randomItems Array

Comment: public class Item
{ public ArrayList<String> randomNames; } - not static? I am not sure what you mean with the second point :)

Comment: Each instance of the class Item has a randomNames array inside it. Therefore in the constructor of Item you must add your values to the array. The code:randomNames.add("Key");
randomNames.add("Rock");
randomNames.add("Balloon");
randomNames.add("Boot");
randomNames.add("Knife");
randomNames.add("Pencil");
Should be inside "Item" constructor. Otherwise the array will be created empty when the Item is created.

Comment: Ahh.. That's it! It works. Thank you!! :D The problem was exactly that the array is created empty :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you instantiated your list ?

```
randomNames = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then you can add all the items you want.

Comment: I did that in field, yes :) and adding items to the arraylist works fine :)

Comment: There's something not in your reported code which causes the problem

Comment: There is NO other code refering to the randomItem class or randomNames arraylist at all.. :s

Comment: I would write in the 'Item' constructor 'randomNames = new ArrayList<String>();' then write 'Item randomItem;
randomItem = new Item("NAME_HERE", "DESCRIPTION_HERE", 0000);

Comment: sry, then write randomItem = new Item("NAME_HERE", "DESCRIPTION_HERE", 0000);  randomItem.randomNames.add("Key");
randomItem.randomNames.add("Rock");
This can't work

Comment: The only difference between that and what i already did, is to add (randomItem.randomNames.add("Key"); OUTSIDE of the class instead of just randomnames.add("Key"); inside the class?

Comment: Try to add your Strings to the List directly in the Item constructor

Comment: By using randomNames.add("key") in the constructor, or is there another way to add strings to it as i declare it with randomNames = new ArrayList<String>(); ?

Comment: The more object-oriented solution is to make your List a private field of Item class. In the Item constructor you instantiate the list (new ArrayList) then you create a method void addRandomName(String random){ randomNames.add(random); } and a method List<String> getRandomNames(){ return randomNames; }